# Pandas function equivalent to hlookup in excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, series

There is this df "`creditor_life_rates_tranpose`" which is a lookup table:

[image]

I am trying to look up the value based on keys "`age`" and "`term_years`" and store back to my base data frame "application".

For test data, the base dataframe "`application`" contains  columns "`age`", "`term_years`" with values 49 and 3.8 respectfully.

Base dataframe application is below:

```
age, terms_years
49, 3.8
```

We see that age 49 is located in the lookup table but since 3.8 is not located in the `term_years` column of the lookup table I need it to look up using the highest value which is lower than 3.8. In this case it would be 3.5. **Hence the value which should be returned is 21.40.**

I had tried to write this function using tail(1) to return only the last value based on the `age` and `terms_years` from the lookup table

```
def hlookup_function(age, terms_year):
result=  creditor_life_rates_tranpose[(creditor_life_rates_tranpose['age']== age) & (creditor_life_rates_tranpose['term_years'] <= terms_year)]['value'].tail(1).values[0]

return result
```

Then I would call the function like this:

```
application['result'] = hlookup_function(application.age,(application_data.term_years).round(2))
```

*I was expecting to get this as the resulting Dataframe:*

```
age, terms_years, results
49, 3.8, 21.40
```

but i am getting this error:
[image]

By the way, the code works if I pass the values like this but not the actual columns of the application dataframe. But I need to actually pass the columns.

```
application['result'] = hlookup_function(49,3.8)
```

Comment: Kindly provide sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: [pd.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks! Pandas is so powerful. This is function I was looking for. It does exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This function [pd.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) performs the operation I was looking for and is equivalent to the HLOOKUP function in Excel.

```
application_data2 = pd.merge_asof(application_data.sort_values(by=['term_years_lookup'],ascending=True)
,creditor_life_rates_tranpose.sort_values(by=['term_years_lookup'],ascending=True), 
on='term_years_lookup',by ='age_lookup')
```